# redirect into page with data in ajax codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to redirect into page with ajax function in codeigniter framework

i have ajax function in my first page i am passing some input value through ajax to controller function after performing action i want to redirect on same function view page

my ajax function is look like

```
function search()
{
   var city = $('input[name="city"]').val();
   var location = $("#location").val();
   var cat = $("#cat").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url()."Fitness/studios"; ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data:'city='+ city + '&location='+ location + '&cat='+ cat ,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success'){
                window.location = "<?php echo base_url();"Fitness/studios"?>";
            } 
        }

    });
}
```

and my controller function is

```
public function studios()
{
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $data['studios']= $this->Welcome_model->selectstudios($city,$location,$cat);

    if($data['studios'])
    {
      $data['status']= "success";  
    }
    $this->load->view('studiolist', $data);
}
```

after getting value in `$data['studios']` unable to redirect page on `$this->load->view('studiolist', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller u need to do echo

```
if($data['studios'])
{
  echo "success";  
}
else{
  echo "Failed";
}
```

and in ajax response u need to do like this
post data like this

```
data: {location:$("#location").val(),
city:$("#city").val(),
cat:$("#cat").val()},
if (data == 'success'){
            window.location = "ur location to redirect";
        }
```

in controller access the data like this

```
$this->input->post('fieldname'); insetead of $_post['fieldname'];
```

and remove this line from controller

```
$this->load->view('studiolist', $data);
```

Comment: try after posting data like this

Comment: @Tejaswee : This will work for you, may be you missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like bellow, I hope it will solve your problem

```
$view= $this->load->view('studiolist', $data,TRUE);
$jData=array('data'=>$data,'view'=>$view);
echo json_encode($jData);
```

After pass view you can check in success function of ajax

```
success: function (data) {
console.log("data",data)
            /*if (data.status == 'success'){
                window.location = "<?php echo base_url();"Fitness/studios"?>";
            } */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirect url helper function in codeigniter which may not work in this case so create a custom helper function to over write it:

```
/**
     * Like CodeIgniter redirect(), but uses javascript if needed to redirect out
     * of an ajax request.
     *
     * @param string $url The url to redirect to. If not a full url, will wrap it
     * in site_url().
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function redirect($url = null)
    {
        if (! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $url)) {
            $url = site_url($url);
        }

        if (! self::$ci->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            header("Location: {$url}");

            // The default header specifies the content type as HTML, which requires
            // certain elements to be considered valid. No content is included,
            // so use a content type which does not require any.
            header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        } else {
            // Output URL in a known location and escape it for safety.
            echo '<div id="url" data-url="';
            e($url);
            echo '"></div>';

            // Now JS can grab the URL and perform the redirect.
            echo <<<EOF
<script>
window.location = document.getElementById('url').getAttribute('data-url');
</script>
EOF;
        }

        exit();
    }
```